# How can you manage (force- not recommend) what extensions are enabled/disabled in a VS Code workspace with a configuration file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

You can manage settings for each workspace in the `.vscode/settings` in the root of the workspace folder, it doesn't seem possible to do this with enabling/disabling extensions (unless the extension itself has a setting to enable/disable itself). For example so that extensions can be disabled gloablly and then enable in the workspaces you need them without having to go through the GUI. Obviously you might not have these extensions installed which might be why you can't do it, but that usually means it's someone else working on it which is what extension recommendations in the extensions folder is for, but that's not what I need.

Comment: I edited your question. if I didn't understand what you're looking for right, feel free to roll back the edit. and clarify what exactly you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with many things, the solution to a challenge might not come in exactly the form that you've envisioned. One solution to this challenge is not to set the list of extensions in the workspace, but in a Profile. [Ref](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles)

This is a hotly debated topic [Ref](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/40239) where the current VSCode provides solutions for many similar challenges, but it's not a one mechanism truly fits **all** use cases. And really, how many tools actually fit **all** use cases?

Specifically, a Profile has environment-specific settings that you may or may not wish to mandate for specific workspaces. You have the choice. Here is an example of what a Profile contains:
[image: screenshot of Profile settings]

A Profile can be saved with a workspace, and you can make it a team policy to always load the profile that comes with the workspace from the repo.

When you load a Workspace, it will load with the Profile you last used with it. So you don't need to manually load the Profile with every Workspace. That is - when you open the project, your extensions are modified for that specific Workspace. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75340086/binding-vscode-profiles-to-a-workspace)

The Profile can also be selected from the CLI. There is a CLI `--profile` option to set which Profile to use for the current session. [Ref](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_select-a-profile) If you load VSCode with an alias this can be done automatically for you.

**Summary**: This addresses the presented challenge:

> so that extensions can be disabled gloablly and then enable in the workspaces you need them without having to go through the GUI.

Specifically, you setup your environment as you wish, save the current environment as a Profile, and the next time you open the workspace you have the same settings.
In the bigger picture you'll want several Profiles, one default for "General" projects, maybe one for React, one for Vue one for PHP, one for C++, etc..

**Suggestion**: Try to use Profiles and see if they work for some or all of your use cases. Use them where they fit, and not where they do not.

**Request**: Please don't debate the nuances of the implementation of Profiles in VSCode (*nuanced team use cases, ugly JSON, using .code-profile and not .code-workspace...*). This is an Answer to a Question, and the OP may decide it is their accepted answer - or it may not suit their use cases. Elegance is a different topic which is discussed in the referenced GitHub ticket. If you want to debate elegance, please do it there.

Answer (score 1):

Note that VS Code Profiles allow you to select what extensions to enable/disable globally, and VS Code will remember if you have selected a profile for a particular workspace (see [binding vscode profiles to a workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75340086/11107541)). But I'm not sure if that meets your requirements. Profiles are saved in the user data directory and not in the workspace folder, so to share it with all your collaborators by checking it into the project's version control, you'd need to [export the profile](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles#_share-profiles) into a .code-profile file and have your collaborators import it.

Other than Profiles, the best you can do for configuring what extensions are enabled per-workspace via configuration file is [.vscode/extensions.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_workspace-recommended-extensions) (which you *can* check into version control with the project), which only gives *recommendations* for what extensions to have installed and enabled (`recommendations`) / disabled (`unwantedRecommendations`). There is no file that you can use to force what gets enabled or disabled per workspace (I guess Profiles sort of do this, but it has its limitations). I wager that this is by design to allow each user to make their own choices (I think forcing something upon the user could make for bad user experiences).

Related questions:

- [Is there a way to toggle VS Code extensions per project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71268372/11107541)
- [Where does VSCode store the enabled/disabled state for extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69706490/11107541)

I think what you are looking for is covered by [Feature Request: Enable/disable extensions from config file #40239](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/40239). I suggest that you give that issue ticket a thumbs up reaction to show support for it, and subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and updates. Please avoid making noisy comments like "+1" / "bump", and if you want to participate in the discussion, please read through what has already been discussed to avoid repeating what has already been said.

Comment: Yeah but it's the same with extension settings. It would be better maybe if it was still per workspace, but not in the workspace, so it only applies to a user in the workspace, not everyone in the workspace.

Comment: @isimmons my bad. docs aren't super clear. see edit.